# Instagram Stories on google Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, instagram

How does instagram.com displays stories on full mobile screen(no url bar) when using google chrome as  mobile browser.?Is there any JavaScript trick to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.requestFullscreen`

```js
function toggleFullscreen() {
  let elem = document.documentElement;

  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    elem.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
      alert(`Error attempting to enable full-screen mode: ${err.message} (${err.name})`);
    });
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

For browser compatibility check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen)